# How To Tell When QTreeView is Fully Expanded

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I'm using a QTreeView/QFileSystemModel pairing to display directory contents. I'm loading a large directory, with tens of thousands of files and subdirectories in it. When I issue an expandAll() call, the tree takes a long time to fully open - on the order of 30 seconds or so. I'd like to put up a "Please Wait..." dialog until the tree is completely expanded.

The expandAll() function, though, returns almost immediately. I am looking for a signal that's emitted when the tree is fully expanded, but there doesn't seem to be one. The 'expanded' signal is emitted only for a specific index, and I can't tell which index I should use to indicate complete expansion.

Comment: I don't think QTreeView::expandAll() works asynchronously. Just large amount of item's. Are you sure that expandAll() returns immediately? I'm not. Try QWidget::setUpdatesEnabled(false) before calling expandAll() and enabling updates after that call. Call also QWidget::update() after that, ftw.

Comment: I've got my expandAll() call bracketed with cout statements; their contents appear consecutively pretty much instantly. Meanwhile, the UI is locked for ~30 seconds or so. I noted that this only happens the very first time I do an expandAll() call, so it's probably related to the initial loading of the filesystem structure. Subsequent calls open the tree pretty much instantly.